# Why the Primary Expression '1' is the only number that isn't greater than but is equal to the Primary Expression 'true'?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

Why the Primary Expression '1' is the only number that isn't greater than but is equal to the Primary Expression 'true'?
Am also new to JavaScript and programming in general..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    if (1 > true || 1 < true) {
      document.write("YEA");
    } else if (2 == true) {
      document.write("YEA MAN");
    } else if (2 > true && 1 == true) {
      document.write("WTF BRAH!!");
      // evaluates to the string "WTF BRAH!!"
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You will find that it is unnecessary to compare numbers with bools in a well designed program.

Comment: Documentation: [`==`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality), [`<`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than). Specification: [`==`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) uses [IsLooselyEqual](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal), [`<`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) uses [IsLessThan](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan). Follow the specification steps. `1 == true` coerces to `1 == 1` → `1 === 1` → `true`. `1 < true` coerces to `1 < 1` → `false`.

Comment: _“Am also new to JavaScript”_ — [Don’t use `document.write`](/q/802854/4642212), learn from [MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide), not W3Schools.

Comment: I used document.write for the code snippet for demonstration purpose only, more convenient than console.log when you run code snippet in stack overflow @Sebastian Simon